# How can I use .htaccess to set headers only for some areas of a site and not for others?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set CSP headers for some areas of my website but not for others. The admin area of my site doesn't work with CSP headers but I want the public-facing areas to use them. The admin is all inside a mysite.com/admin/ directory. What I am trying is:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ /admin/">
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';
</If>
```

But it is applying the headers even inside the admin directory.
Is there a way to do it?

Edit: These are the other directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png|staging)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: What other directives do you have? Are you using a front-controller pattern to route your admin pages? (Is the front-controller inside the `/admin` subdirectory?)

Comment: The front controller is index I believe, not in the admin directory but in the root.